# My checking enable module on Magento don't working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento2

I'm developing a php module to Magento 1.9.2.4. I want to check if my module is enable or disable, but it is not working. What is wrong ?

Module folder: `C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Projetos\HelloWorld`

My code:

```
<?php
    require_once 'app/Mage.php';

    Mage::app();

    $moduleName = 'Projetos_HelloWorld';//eg Mage_Cms       
    if(Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig($moduleName)->is('active', 'true')) {
        //$product = new Projetos_HelloWorld_Model_Product;
        //$product->sayHello();
        echo "Module Enable";
     } else {
        echo "Module Disable";
     }
?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'are not following standard magento module creating method.

If you would like to know whether particular module is enable or not then you have to check it from app/etc/modules/name_of_module.xml

Please have a look at how to create an extension in magento.

http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-developper-guide-howto-tutorial-5

I hope this will help you out.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Projetos_HelloWorld'))
{
  echo "Module Enable";
} else {
   echo "Module disabled";
}
```